# how to send form data from one page to another using django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

- **Problem**:I want to send the form data of index.html to greetings.html which show the username on greetings.html, But it is displaying error message

  > NoReverseMatch at /
  >   Reverse for 'greeting.views.greetings' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
  >   Request Method: GET
  >   . Can you suggest a simple
  >   method to send the form data to another page using django.
- **I want a select box which display the option present in list. Inside the form.**

> **greetings/template/index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> </title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'greetings/css/style.css' %}" />
    {% verbatim %}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    {% endverbatim %}
</head>
<body >
  <div class="container-fluid" >
    <div id="home" class="">
              <form class="input-form text-center" name = "form"  method = "POST"  action="{% url 'greetings.views.greetings'%}">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                <h1> Create your wishes </h1>
                  <input type="text" name = "username" placeholder="Enter your name"/>
                  <select name="select">
                      <option value=''>Please Choose your wish</option>
                  </select>
                  <br/>
                  <input id="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Create"/>
              </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **greetings/template/greetings.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo-wish"class="card text-center">
              <h4> {{ username }} </h4>
           <h3> Wishes you </h3>
           <h4> Happy{{ username }} </h4>
          </div>
        <div id="demo" class="card text-center">
            <form>
                <h2>Create Your Wishes</h2>
                <h4>ENTER YOUR NAME TO WISH YOUR FRIENDS AND FAMILY MEMBERS</h4>
                <span>{{ username }}</span><br/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-primary"   value="Go">
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **greetings/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from greetings.forms import LoginForm


def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('greetings/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

def greetings(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get the posted form
        MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
            username = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['username']
    else:
        MyLoginForm = LoginForm()

    return render(request, 'greetings/greetings.html', {"username": username})
```

> **greetings/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> **project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', include('greetings.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

> **greetings/forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
   occasion=['christmas','New Year']
   user = forms.CharField(max_length = 100)
   select = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(choices=occasion))
```

> **Error-Message:**

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'greeting.views.greetings' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'greeting.views.greetings' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Exception Location: C:\Users\Captain America\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.4-py3.6.egg\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 392
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Captain America\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path:    
['D:\\django\\project_greetings',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain '
 'America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain '
 'America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain '
 'America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain '
 'America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Captain '
 'America\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\django-1.10.4-py3.6.egg']
Server time:    Sat, 7 Jan 2017 17:58:39 +0530
```

Comment: @e4c5 sir I have corrected the question. Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the following line that's producing the error

```
<form class="input-form text-center" name = "form"  method = "POST"  action="{% url 'greetings.views.greetings'%}">
```

But whe you look at your urls.py you don't have a view defined like that. So you need to define it first. And then you need to [assign it a name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) if you want to get the link wtih the url tag

> When you name your URL patterns, make sure you use names that are
>   unlikely to clash with any other application’s choice of names. If you
>   call your URL pattern comment, and another application does the same
>   thing, there’s no guarantee which URL will be inserted into your
>   template when you use this name.

In fact, I recommend that you read the whole page. in the link.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have two URLs, url1 for page 1 and url2 for page2 where you want your form data to be sent.

Template of page1
#on click Button we gonna direct to page2 i.e. url2

```
<form action="{% url 'url2' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="var_name" value="var_value" class="class_name">Button</button>
</form>
```

views.py of page2

```
if 'var_name' in request.POST:
    #context is the name of dict that we gonna pass to our template
    #'var_name' derives from the template of page1
    context["name"] = request.POST['var_name']
return render(request, 'page2.html', context)
```

Template of page2
#thus we can finally get the value from page1 which we store in 'name' var

```
<p>{{name}}</p>
```